# How do I send an HTTP Response that's an array-wrapped JSON? ([][]byte)

Tags: arrays, json

If I use the standard library to make this response, the type Writer Interface only takes a slice of bytes as an argument, but an array wrapped JSON is [][]byte

I know there must be something I'm missing here...

And as a note, I tried using the Echo Framework for this and it does successfully send but it's auto encoding the contents into base64 which is not what I want for my API right now.

```
json, err := json.Marshal(j)
check(err)

arrJSON := [][]byte {
    json,
}
fmt.Printf("arrJSON: %s", arrJSON) // this prints correctly

return c.JSONPretty(http.StatusOK, arrJSON, "") //this returns a base64 encoded array wrapped JSON (it works but I wan't decoded)
```